# Azure Bicep - Logic App with Integration Service - Could not find member 'apiVersion' on object of type 'IntegrationAccountReference

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create a bicep template that deploys a Logic App. The logic app has integration account that one of the actions use to execute a JavaScript snippet.

Whether I use an existing Integration Account or create a new one, I end up with the below error

> Could not find member 'apiVersion' on object of type 'IntegrationAccountReference.  Path 'properties.integrationAccount.apiVersion'

I've tried using the 2016 and also the 2019 version of the api without any luck. What am I missing here ?

```
resource logicAppIntegrationAccount 'Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts@2016-06-01' existing = {
  name: 'integrationAccountName'
}



resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2016-06-01' = {
  name: logicapp_name
  location: location
    properties: {
    definition: logicAppDefinition.definition
    parameters: logicAppDefinition.parameters
    integrationAccount:logicAppIntegrationAccount
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.logic/workflows?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#resourcereference), the `integrationAccount` property on the logic app resource is an object:

```bicep
resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicapp_name
  location: location
    properties: {
    definition: logicAppDefinition.definition
    parameters: logicAppDefinition.parameters
    integrationAccount: {
      id: logicAppIntegrationAccount.id
    }
  }
}
```